# Can't set up proxy for Raspbian

Tags: proxy, raspbian, apt-get

I need to connect a Raspberry Pi to proxy, and after everything that I've tried, it can't connect to the internet via the proxy.

Things I've tried:

- Created `10proxy` in `\etc\apt\apt.conf.d`
- Edited `sudoers`
- Edited `environment`

I scoured the internet for answers, and there apparently isn't any that isn't the three, which all don't work.

Please help!